# How can I use beautiful soup to get the following data from kick starter?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some data from kick starter. How can use beautiful soup library?

Kick Starter link
https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?woe_id=2347575&sort=magic&seed=2600008&page=7

These are the following information I need

```
Crowdfunding goal
Total crowdfunding
Total backers
Length of the campaign (# of days)
```

This is my current code

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?woe_id=2347575&sort=magic&seed=2600008&page=1')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'js-react-proj-card grid-col-12 grid-col-6-sm grid-col-4-lg'})
len(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

i'll give you some of hint that i know, and hope you can do by yourself.

1. crawling has legal problem when you abuse Term of Service.
2. `find_all` should use with 'for' statment. it works like `find all` on web page(Ctrl + f).

e.g.

```
for a in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'js-react-proj-card grid-col-12 grid-col-6-sm grid-col-4-lg'}):
     print (a)
```

3.links should be open 'for' statement. - https://www.kickstarte...seed=2600008&page=**1**

bold number repeated in for statement, so you can crawling all data In orderly

4.you sholud linked twice. - above link, there is list of pj. you should get link of these pj.

so code's algorithm likes this.

```
    for i in range(0,10000):
        url = www.kick.....page=i
        for pj_link in find_all(each pj's link):
            r2 = requests.get(pj_link)
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')
......
```